# Transpose rows to columns in linux

Tags: linux, unix

Input (in a file) is like below -

```
IndexName      ColumnName
Ind1           Col1
Ind1           Col2
Ind2           Col3
```

Now how to generate below output using linux , please sed or awk or other inbuilt functions -

```
IndexName      ColumnName
Ind1           ("Col1","Col2")
Ind2           ("Col3")
```

Thanks ,

Comment: [Pivoting table content using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33251131/608639) and friends. More generally, [bash pivot table site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+pivot+table+site:stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

Here's some ugly awk that I'm certain can be written more elegantly. Also, for the record, this is more "String aggregation" and less "Transpose".

```
awk -v quote='"' 'NR==1{print $0}NR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]","quote$2quote}END{for (ind in a){print ind, "("substr(a[ind], 2, length(a[ind])-1)")"}}'
```